# Evaluate the indicated definite integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^1 (e^ {2x} + 4 \sqrt[3]{x}) dx\ $$

I started doing it like this:

$$= \frac {1} 2  \int e^u du \\=  \frac { 1} 2 e^u\\= \frac { 1} 2 e^{2x}  $$

I got stuck, any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the two integrals separately
$$\int_0^1 e^{2x}=\frac12 e^{2x}\Bigg|_0^1$$
and

$$4\int_0^1\sqrt[3]{x}dx=3 x^{4/3}\Bigg|_0^1$$
Now evaluate the two expressions and sum it.

Answer (score 1):

Here we do not seem to need substitution:

$\int_0^1(e^{2x}+4x^{\frac{1}{3}})dx=\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}+3x^{\frac{4}{3}}|_0^1=\frac{1}{2}e^2+3-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(e^2+5).$